# Problema con git al hacer merge de una rama secundario a MASTER

Tags: github, git-bash

tengo dos ramas :

**Rama Jose**

`esto es de jose.txt` 
`index.html`

**Rama master**

`index.html`

Y quiero pasar lo que tengo en la rama **jose** a la rama **master** (el fichero `esto es de jose.txt`).

Primero me pongo en la rama donde quiero pasar lo nuevo (en este caso la rama **master**). Es decir, hago los siguientes pasos:

Me paso a **master**
`git checkout master`

Le mezclo lo que tiene **jose**
`git merge jose`

Y finalmente deberia de hacer un **push** con lo que ha **mergeado de 'jose'**:

`git push origin master`

al hacer eso me da el siguiente error :

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/.......'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Entonces **creo** que como se me ha quedado es que en el **branch master** tengo en **local** el fichero de **jose** (el fichero `esto es de jose.txt`) pero en mi **url de github** (la nube)  no. Es decir esta en mi contenedor local pero no comiteado.

Comment: ¿No tendras master protegida en el server del git?

Comment: ya encontre el fallo, es que no hice commit despues de hacer merge !!